# Apache Mina UDP Client: java.net.PortUnreachableException

Tags: java, sockets, udp, apache-mina

There seems to be no documentation anywhere about the `java.net.PortUnreachableException`.

I've made a simple Apache Mina UDP Server and ran it. I then used `telnet 127.0.0.1 3450` to check whether it was listening, and the connection was not refused, so the server definitely works.

The client consisits of the following files.

This is the main class below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("started");
    NioDatagramConnector connector = new NioDatagramConnector();

    connector.setHandler(new PacketHandler());
    ConnectFuture cf = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 3450));
}
```

This is part of the PacketHandler class:

```
@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession s) {
    System.out.println("opened " + s.getId() + " " + s.getLocalAddress().toString() + " " + s.getRemoteAddress().toString());
    byte[] data = new byte[]{(byte) 0x01};
    System.out.println("Sending " + data.length);
    IoBuffer buffer = IoBuffer.allocate(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();
    s.write(buffer);
}
```

When the client is ran, I get the following error:

```
started
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
created 1
opened 1 /127.0.0.1:56777 /127.0.0.1:3450
Sending 1
java.net.PortUnreachableException
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.read(DatagramDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.read(DatagramChannelImpl.java:560)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:311)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:45)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:702)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:668)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:657)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1121)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
closed 1
```

The server also logs connections and when the client is ran, no connections are logged. However, when the `telnet 127.0.0.1 3450` is ran from my Terminal, a connection is logged in the server logs. So apparently, the client isn't actually connecting.

Comment: Telnet doesn't prove anything about UDP ports. It tests TCP ports. You didn't have a UDP socket open at the port you connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet can't connect to UDP. You are therefore testing a TCP server with Telnet, which proves nothing.

check the code,you can paste it here.

Comment: @Michaël Certainly it does, and a correct answer at that.